# opensuse: cannot install proprietary graphic driver fglrx

Tags: drivers, opensuse, graphics, radeon

I installed OpenSUSE 13.1 in dual boot on my Samsung ATIV Book 6 pre-installed with Windows 8 with a USB key (ultrabook, no DVD reader at the moment).

I tried to install the proprietary driver fglrx following every different procedure indicated in http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:AMD_fglrx but after rebooting, I get a black screen. 
I therefore tried the 1-click procedure, the yast, the zipper command-line and the script from the german fellow. Concerning the last one, the script failed and stated that my graphic card (Radeon HD 8850M) was not compatible.

Here is the Xorg log when I booted with fglrx installed and without nomodeset option: http://susepaste.org/88126850

Answer (score 1):

> the script failed and stated that my graphic card (Radeon HD 8850M) was not compatible.

This probably means what it says.  That card is not on [this list](http://en.opensuse.org/HCL%3aAMD_video_cards#Supported_Hardware_AMD_fglrx_driver).  If you scroll up, the "FireGL 8800/8700" is on the open source Radeon list, I dunno if that is applicable.

[This article](http://ubuntuxtreme.com/news/amd-catalyst-13-2-beta-3-driver-up-to-300-performance/) from a year ago claims the 13.**2** beta driver might be the *first* support for the AMD Radeon 8000, so you could look into that.

Comment: I looked at your list and got worried but the article is still 7 months old. I found that the 13.9 driver http://driverscollection.com/?H=Radeon%20HD%208850M&By=AMD is supposed to support my card. The script I tried was using the 13.12 driver so my card should be supported, should not it be?